# how to use mongo-hadoop to access mongodb collection whose name is "my.study.stable"

Tags: mongodb, hive, connector

There is a collection named 'my.study.stable' in mongodb.
Now I use the MongoDB Connector for Hadoop(hive) to connect the collection.
My create statement is

```html
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable(
 song_id BIGINT,
 ctime BIGINT
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'=
'{"song_id":"_id",
"ctime":"ctime"}') 
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://username:password@host:port/mzk_spiders.my.study.stable');
```

The create statement excutes success.But when I query data,I occur error like this:

```html
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to aggregate sample documents. Note that this Splitter implementation is incompatible with MongoDB versions prior to 3.2.
```

Comment: the collection's size is about 4.3G

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same error

Comment: Got it working, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The error is produced due to the `SampleSplitter` inability to handle large amounts of data coming from MongoDB, so to solve this specify a different splitter in the line you're using to invoke hadoop, like in `mongo.splitter.class=com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.StandaloneMongoSplitter`